# display a picture based on conditional XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using the following code to try and display a picture IF a check box is activated and nothing if it is not.

I am trying to "sledgehammer" existing code into doing this for me and I have come up with this:

```
<div>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@FaceForward != ''">
<img style="border:1px solid; margin:5px 15px 5px 15px; width:125px;" src="{substring-   before(@Picture,',')}" /> 
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</div>
```

I am not sure if this will produce the expected result, and I am just wondering fi someone with more knowledge / experience with XSL can have a quick look and say "yes" this will work or "no" here is a better way.

Again nice and simple. If a box is checked a picture appears. If the box is empty nothing appears.

Comment: I guess it could work. Have you actually tried it? Do you actually have a problem to solve?

Comment: What is the value of a checked box?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an if block instead.  I couldn't tell you if the following will work without seeing the input XML.

```
<div>
  <xsl:if test="@FaceForward != ''">
    <img style="border:1px solid; margin:5px 15px 5px 15px; width:125px;" src="{substring-before(@Picture,',')}" /> 
  </xsl:if>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly it's not displaying anything. I have actually modded the code slightly to be:

    <div>
    <xsl:if test="@FaceForward != ''">
    <img src="/PublishingImages/Graphics/ff_up_north_180.jpg" alt="Face Forward"/> 
    </xsl:if>
    </div>

Not sure what you mean by input XML. I am pulling the information from a Sharepoint list. One of the items in the list is a check box called "FaceForward" and if checked I want the image (from the above code) to display.

Comment: @michael.hor257k has a great example to shorter it even further (without the `!= ''` usage. Follow that example, and if the image isn't displaying, my best guess is that the image source is bad and/or `@FaceForward` is suppose to actually hold a value whether button is pressed or not, ie. "FaceForward" is 1 when pressed, 0 when not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In a boolean test, a string is true if it's not empty - so you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:if test="@FaceForward">
    <!-- do stuff -->
</xsl:if>
```

No need to use choose if you don't have multiple (at least two) choices.